# Authentication in MERN stack application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, cookies, jwt

I am working on a MERN stack project and want to authenticate users, but don't know which method to use. I am stuck with JWT tokens, but can't really get my head around about it generally.

Comment: Could you describe your question more clearly? Like whether you have your user auth system or using 3rd party tools or do you have any issues with the library, also share your code

Answer (score 0):

search about http only cookie which sends the token in cookie for further more security

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).